# How to handle recursion?

Tags: c++, recursion, visual-c++, stack-overflow

A 2D array represent an image, each pixel has a color, this recursive function job is to transform a region of the same color (c) surrounding pixel (x,y) to a new color (newC).The function is working fine until i pass a large number like x=200, y=200 and a SO occurs.
How can i handle this case? or if there is a better solution other than recursion?

```
void Region(int x, int y, char newC, char c) { //c is current color, newC is new Color
    if(c == newC) return;
    arr[y][x]=newC;
    if(arr[y][x-1 ]== c && x-1 > 0) Region(x-1, y, newC, c);
    if(arr[y-1][x] == c && y-1 > 0) Region(x, y-1, newC, c);
    if(arr[y][x+1] == c && x+1 <= M) Region(x+1, y, newC, c);
    if(arr[y+1][x] == c && y+1 <= N) Region(x, y+1, newC, c);
}
```

Example of 2 regions (Os & Vs):

OOOOOO
OOVOOO
OVVVOO
OVVOOO
OVOOOO

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about a [flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill), in which case it's better to use stack-based recursion as described in the link.

Comment: @RogerRowland
Thanks the link was helpful!  

I would appreciate if anybody tells me whats wrong with the code :  

`void Region(int x,int y,char newC,char c)
{
 
 char n;
 if(c==newC)return;
 myqueue.empty();
 myqueue.push_back(arr[y][x]);
 while (myqueue.size()!=0)
 {
  n=myqueue.back();
  myqueue.pop_back();
  if(n==c)
  {
   n=newC;
   if(x-1>0)myqueue.push_back(arr[y][x-1]);
   if(y-1>0)myqueue.push_back(arr[y-1][x]);
   if(x+1<=M)myqueue.push_back(arr[y][x+1]);
   if(y+1<=N)myqueue.push_back(arr[y+1][x]);
  }
 }

}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the link there was a more efficient solution than the recursion

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Flood-fill (node, target-color, replacement-color):

```
1. If target-color is equal to replacement-color, return.
2. Set Q to the empty queue.
3. Add node to the end of Q.
4. While Q is not empty: 
5.     Set n equal to the last element of Q.
6.     Remove last element from Q.
7.     If the color of n is equal to target-color:
8.         Set the color of n to replacement-color.
9.         Add west node to end of Q.
10.        Add east node to end of Q.
11.        Add north node to end of Q.
12.        Add south node to end of Q.
13. Return.
```

This is my first attempt at transforming the pseudo code to C++:

```
std::deque<char> myqueue;
void Region(int x,int y,char newC,char c)
{
    char n;
    if(c==newC)return;
    myqueue.empty();
    myqueue.push_back(arr[y][x]);
    while (myqueue.size()!=0)
    {
        n=myqueue.back();
        myqueue.pop_back();
        if(n==c)
        {
            n=newC;
            if(x-1>0)    myqueue.push_back(arr[y][x-1]);
            if(y-1>0)    myqueue.push_back(arr[y-1][x]);
            if(x+1<=M)   myqueue.push_back(arr[y][x+1]);
            if(y+1<=N)   myqueue.push_back(arr[y+1][x]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The line `n=newC;` should probably be something like `arr[y][x]=newC`, otherwise you're not updating the array with the new colour.  You would also need to push the x+y coordinates onto the queue, rather than the character so that you know which element you are dealing with at each iteration of the while loop.

Answer (score -1):

Since your changing the entire thing into ONE color, why don't you just use 2 nested for loops, then you won't have to do your if statement checks, therefore your function won't be recursive.

Try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < y; i++){
  for(int j = 0; j < x; j++){
      arr[i][j] = newC;
  }
}
```

Comment: Not the entire thing, by region i mean :
The region R to be filled is defined as follows. The pixel (X,Y) belongs to this region. The other pixel belongs to the region R if and only if it has the same colour as pixel (X,Y) and a common side with any pixel which belongs to this region.

Thanks anyway :)

Comment: So you want to change the color of a Y amount of X pixels? I think the nested loops will still work for a region you just have to set y and x correctly and they'll do the rest.

Comment: I don't completely understand which pixels you want to change, maybe you can show how a region would change from one color to another?

Comment: OOOOOO  OOVOOO  OVVVOO  OVVOOO  OVOOOO  

here i have 2 regions Vs region and Os region
there is a break line between each string

Comment: A flood fill changes the element specified and any elements of the same value next to it, so in the example in the question, if you selected 2,2 then all of the Vs would be changed to the new value.  However, if there had been a V in the bottom right, it would not have been changed because it wasn't connected to the start point of the flood fill.  Your current answer doesn't address the question at all.